# Rock, Paper, Scissors doesn't let user win

Tags: python, while-loop

```
#RoShamBo
import random
count=0
while count<2 and count> -2:
    compnum=random.randint(0,2)
    usernum=int(input("Scissor(0), Rock(1), Paper(2)"))
    if compnum==0:
        if usernum==0:
            print("Draw")
        elif usernum==1:
            print("Win")
            count=count+1
        elif usernum==2:
            print("Lose")
            count=count-1
    elif compnum==1:
        if usernum==0:
            print("Lose")
            count=count-1
        elif usernum==1:
            print("Draw")
        elif usernum==2:
            print("Win")
            count=count+1
    elif compnum==2:
        if usernum==0:
            print("Win")
            count=count+1
        elif usernum==1:
            print("Lose")
            count=count-1
        elif usernum==2:
            print("Draw")
if count>2:
    print("You won more than 2 times")
else:
    print("The computer won more than 2 times")
```

The output is messed up -- for one thing, it won't let the user win. Also, it's not calculating the numbers properly. This was a lab assignment for a class in introduction to Python, but the professor I believe wrote the code incorrectly. Here's a sample broken output:

```
============== RESTART: C:/Users/FieryAssElsa/Desktop/Broken.py ==============
    Scissor(0), Rock(1), Paper(2)2
    Draw
    Scissor(0), Rock(1), Paper(2)2
    Win
    Scissor(0), Rock(1), Paper(2)2
    Draw
    Scissor(0), Rock(1), Paper(2)2
    Lose
    Scissor(0), Rock(1), Paper(2)2
    Win
    Scissor(0), Rock(1), Paper(2)2
    Win
    The computer won more than 2 times
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You will *always* see `The computer won more than 2 times` because the loop continues until `count` is 2 or -2, and then it reaches the condition. Now that `count` is 2 or -2 and 2 is not greater than 2 or -2 it goes to the else block

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with `if count==2:`

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Comment: But I'm trying to say "more than" 2 times.

Comment: @FrostyElsa `count > 2` will never be true.

Comment: My head is about to explode. Okay, so what you're saying is because the while loop set the parameters, it is not possible for count to exceed 2. So to fix that, if we set count COMPARED to 2 (or maybe 3?) that will fix the problem.